# Flush Material Update to HTML in Aframe

Tags: aframe

```
var obj = document.querySelector("#sphere");
obj.components.material.data.roughness = 0.3;
obj.components.material.update(object); 
obj.components.material.flushToDOM();
//I don't think object matters for this use,
//  it is only useful for shaders I believe.
```

I am trying to "flushToDOM()", but that doesn't seem to update the entity html material at all it is still stuck at initial settings...

```
<a-sphere id="sphere" position="0 0.25 -4.5" radius="1.25" color="#712ef0" transparent="true" material="color:#712ef0;transparent:true;metalness:0.3;opacity:1" geometry="primitive:sphere;radius:1.25" rotation="0 0 0" scale="1 1 1">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `setAttribute('material', 'roughness', 0.3)`.

But there might be a bug with flushing "sub-components" like shaders and geometries. Will check out the issue.

Comment: That was fast, will try and mark as correct in a minute. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, it won't let me accept the answer so quickly... But that worked perfectly, wow I have been trying different methods for quite some time. Thanks. Will mark correct in ~9 minutes